# How to periodically save partially computed models in R?

Tags: r, server, stan

I am running a rstan Bayesian predictive model in R which takes about 60 hours to determine the results. I'm currently doing this on my local desktop so I just keep it running till it's done, but we plan to put it on a server which may be affected by unpredictible downtimes. Is there any way to, say, partially save the binaries so that the program resumes from where it left off before the server went down?

I'm not sure if this question follows all the rules of SO or if it has been answered before-in either case it would be great if you could point to an alternative resource before flagging it :)

Thanks

Comment: Can you give example code?

Comment: `save` saves a binary of an object, but I'm not sure it's what you're after.

Answer (score 2):

If you can, the best thing would be to build some checkpointing into the R code using `save`, `save.image` or `saveRDS` as appropriate. If you can't (because for example the time is all spent in C code), then you could look at something more generic.

A generic solution that should work for any running task on recent versions of Linux is to use [criu](http://www.criu.org). There are a couple of caveats to this approach. Firstly, `criu` must be run as root, typically using `sudo`. If you don't have root privileges on the server you're running your code on, this may be a dealbreaker. You (or an administrator) could add `criu` to /etc/suoders, but clearly this has security implications, particularly since `criu` can run an arbitrary action script which will also be run with root privileges.

If you do have the ability to run processes as root, and are happy with the potential security issues, then here is a solution. I'm assuming you have an R script called 'long-running-script.r'.

Here's the files needed:

run-long-run.sh:

```
#!/bin/bash
set -e
if [ -d "r-criu-current" ]
then
  RPID=$(ls r-criu-current/core*.img |perl -pe's/.*?(\d+)\.img/\1/')
  if (ps -p$RPID >/dev/null) then
    ps -p$RPID
    echo "A process is already running with the PID $RPID; perhaps the old process hasn't exited."
    exit 1
  fi
  bash r-criu-pre-restore.sh
  criu restore -D r-criu-current &
else
  setsid Rscript "long-running-script.r" </dev/null &>r-criu.log &
  RPID=$!
fi
echo $RPID
mkdir -p r-criu-current
while :; do
  sleep 5m # Change if needed
  if kill -0 "$RPID" 2>/dev/null
  then
    mkdir -p r-criu-temp
    criu dump -t $RPID --leave-running -D r-criu-temp --action-script ../r-criu-post-dump.sh
    rm -rf r-criu-old || true
    mv r-criu-current r-criu-old
    mv r-criu-temp r-criu-current
    echo "Snapshot saved at "$(date)
  else
    echo "R finished"
    exit
  fi
done
```

r-criu-pre-restore.sh:

```
#!/bin/bash
cp r-criu-current/r-criu.log .
```

r-criu-post-dump.sh: (note that this will have a working directory within r-criu-temp and so needs to reference the files using `..`)

```
#!/bin/bash
[ "$CRTOOLS_SCRIPT_ACTION" = post-dump ] || exit 0
cp ../r-criu.log .
```

long-running.script.r:

```
i <- 0
while(TRUE) {
  i <- i + 1
  cat(i, "\n")
  Sys.sleep(10)
}
```

What the main script does is to check for a previously checkpoint. If it exists, and the process isn't still running, it restores the process from that checkpoint. If there isn't, it starts the script from scratch in a new session and with output redirected to a log file. Then, every 5 minutes (though this can be varied) the script calls `criu` to checkpoint the running R process while still leaving it running. The `r-criu-post-dump.sh` script is used to ensure any files are preserved as they were at the time of the dump. In this case, only the log file is being altered, but other files could be copied as necessary. These files are then restored prior to restoring the checkpoint.

At each time point, there should be two checkpoints kept, the current one and the most recent previous one. This is to guard against there being a crash/power failure while creating/moving the checkpoints.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed comments. I'm not sure whether this will work or not, but I'll check. Thanks for your help :)

Comment: This answer is interesting but is necessitated by the fact that Stan does not currently have any internal mechanism to save its state or input a state.

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure you need to run for 60 hours?  What effective sample size do you need?  How long does it take before the chains converge?  Also, there are various ways to speed up Stan programs through vectorization, using sufficient statistics, redefining variables in earlier blocks, reusing repeated subexpressions, replacing multivariate normals with diagonal covariance matrices with vectorized univariate normals, reparameterizing based on data size, etc.  Feel fee to drop us a line on the Stan users group---there are more Stan users and developers listening there (though as you can see from me and Ben jumping on, we're monitoring stackoverflow now, too).

You can stream out draws with CmdStan.  There's no way to save adaptation state until you get to the end of warmup, and even then, no way yet to restart with that state, so it won't solve your problem.

We're in the middle of refactoring the underlying C++ command structure for Stan 3 that'll make it possible to both save state and restart.

Comment: Thanks professor . I have already gotten my code checked by the mailing list some time back, and some of you already helped me with vectorization and removal of diogonal matrices...so I think it's already -at least somewhat-optimized for performance. I am using iter=1000, chains=4. I am also surprised tht it took me 60 hours to run through 25000 lines of data (only!) . One thing which contribute a bit to the time is that there are some 800 groups in the level-2 of the hierarchy(so i have a 800 x 5 x 2000 parameter matrix).

Comment: However, a similar model with 3 instead of 5 betas was running at around 8 hours previously so I donot know what changed.I do not know if this has got anything to do with the fact that I upgraded to the latest release of rstan.
Most of the convergence happen within a few hundreds of iterations and only some take all of the 2000 iterations.